# C# mouse hook into specific process

Tags: c#, hook

I am running an app where I would like single left button mouse clicks to be repeated while the left mouse button is held down (so basically removing the need to keep clicking).  I wrote a small test app that hooks into the mouse events and listens for the lb down/up events.  However, the app listens to mouse clicks anywhere on my desktop. Is there a way to make it listen to just a specific process?

Here is the test app I am using to listen for mouse clicks:

```
class Program
{
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        private static bool _leftButtonDown;

        public static void Main()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
            Application.Run();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 &&
                MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                _leftButtonDown = false;
                Console.WriteLine(_leftButtonDown);
            }

            if (nCode >= 0 &&
                MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                _leftButtonDown = true;
                Console.WriteLine(_leftButtonDown);
                StartTest();
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private static void StartTest()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (_leftButtonDown)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("SENDING");
                    }
                });
        }

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern uint SendInput(uint numberOfInputs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] INPUT[] input, int structSize);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MOUSEINPUT
        {
            public int dx;
            public int dy;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct KEYBDINPUT
        {
            public ushort wVk;
            public ushort wScan;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct HARDWAREINPUT
        {
            uint uMsg;
            ushort wParamL;
            ushort wParamH;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct INPUT
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public int type;
            [FieldOffset(4)] //*
            public MOUSEINPUT mi;
            [FieldOffset(4)] //*
            public KEYBDINPUT ki;
            [FieldOffset(4)] //*
            public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 4th argument of `SetWindowsHookEx()`, the `dwThreadId` argument, to be selective.  You need to pass the thread ID of the GUI thread of the process you want to monitor.  Obtain the value with, say, `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` if you have a handle of one of the windows owned by the process.  If it is your own process then use `GetCurrentThreadId()`.  If it is a Winforms app then favor `IMessageFilter` instead of a hook.